# Top value in a column that is not #N/A

Tags: excel

I am trying to get the top value from a column that is not #N/A. For instance, I have the following values in column G:

## N/A

## N/A

0.5
1.3

## N/A

2.1
5.6

I am trying to get the top value from the column, but if it is #N/A, the next value that is not #N/A.

I tried the following formula:

=IF(ISNA('10yrTreasury'!G2),('10yrTreasury'!G3/100),IF(ISNA('10yrTreasury'!G3),('10yrTreasury'!G4/100),IF(ISNA('10yrTreasury'!G4),('10yrTreasury'!G5/100))))

But it returns #N/A.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: I am pretty sure that is a column. Can you put an output example as well?

Comment: Yes, it is; sorry for the confusion. I changed the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this array formula

`=INDEX('10yrTreasury'!G2:G5,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER('10yrTreasury'!G2:G5),0))/100`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

That finds the first number, so it works if the "N/A" values are text or actual errors